# How do async tests work in intern?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, intern

How do asynchronous tests work in Intern testing framework? I have tried to get them run exactly as in the example, but the async test passes immediately without waiting for the callback to be run.

```
it('should connect in 5 seconds', function () {
    var dfd = this.async(5000);
    conn.connect(credentials, dfd.callback(function(result) {
        expect(result).to.... something
    }));
}
```

The test passes immediately. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the test is passing because the callback _is_ called as expected and the assertion within your callback happens to pass? I'm guessing you verified that the callback isn't called though. Just a thought.

Comment: Well, `conn.connect` must perform async request, but the callback is triggered before any XMLHttpRequest happens.

Comment: Well, I have figured out the callback is triggered even before the connection is established. However, `result` variable holds the status and I need to check it only when the status equals certain value. Can I say something like 'this is not my case, call the callback again when you hit another result'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dfd.callback` doesn’t execute anything until it itself is executed. Keep in mind that it is designed for promise callbacks (i.e. the function passed to `promise.then`), not Node.js-style callbacks where the argument might be an error (i.e. `function (error, result) {}`). It will not check to see if an error is passed as an argument.

Without knowing what `conn` is, but seeing how you are passing `dfd.callback` as an argument to something that is not a promise, my suspicion is you are trying to use a Node.js-style callback and the call is erroring immediately. We may provide a convenience wrapper for these types of callbacks in the future to convert them to a promise interface, but until then, you probably just need to do something like this:

```js
it('should connect in 5 seconds', function () {
    var dfd = this.async(5000);
    conn.connect(credentials, dfd.callback(function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }

        expect(result).to.... something
    }));
});
```

Otherwise, without knowing what `conn` is and seeing what your actual assertion is, it’s too hard to say what the issue is here. So long as nothing inside the callback throws an error, the test will be considered successful.

**Edit:** So based on your comments above it sounds like your callback is an event listener called multiple times with different information. In this case, what you could do is something like this:

```js
it('should connect in 5 seconds', function () {
    var dfd = this.async(5000);
    conn.connect(credentials, dfd.rejectOnError(function (result) {
        if (result !== 'what I want') {
            return;
        }

        expect(result).to.... something
        // all other tests…

        // nothing threw an error, so it is a successful test
        dfd.resolve();
    }));
});
```

`dfd.rejectOnError` works just like `dfd.callback` except it does not automatically resolve the promise; you do that yourself at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Look at my comment above - I describe the problem there.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is okay. `dfd` sets a timeout of 5 seconds for the test to succeed, then immediately tries `conn.connect()`, which is not part of the intern framework. If you are trying a simple XHR request, try the `getUrlCallback` function instead.

They have a pretty cool list of tests at this url: https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Writing-Tests . Look for the two async examples.